# Docker for Windows: Mounting volumes not working with dockerized postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm running Docker on a Windows 10 machine. I'm trying to run a dockerized postgresql database, whose data can be mounted on my Windows 10 machine. I then want to be able to push this database data on a GitLab repository. If any other user wants to use the newest version of the database after that, he just needs to pull the changes and then mount the data on a dockerized postgresql.

Why do I want to do that?

We'll, there will be a lot of changes in this database. People are also working simultaneous on different version of our program. With a persistent database I would need to manage different versions of the database for every single feature branch, develop branch and master/release branch. That's just too much to handle. So ideally any changes made of the database for a specific feature branch can only be found in this specific feature branch. There would be no conflicts. It also allows to experiment with the database, without destroying it for any other user.

Well, what is the problem then?

Docker for Windows comes with limitations, see: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/445

TL;DR: Right now it's not possible to mount volumes from Windows to Linux containers. There are workarounds for that, as it's said in the link, but no to get those data from the database, to actively push/share it etc., but just to have a database persistent on a local system.

Well, I tried almost anything my mind came up with:

Did a docker-compose, used named volumes and I also tried to use

`/c/this/is/my/windows/path:this/is/my/linux/path`

instead of

`C:\this\is\my\windows\path:this/is/my/linux/path`

but it didn't help either.

I also used, as said before, named volumes in a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgress
      - POSTGRES_DB=lol
  ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  volumes: 
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data: {}
```

But guess what: It still failed.

I know I can create dump of my database and push that, but the problem here is: I dont want to do that manually all the time. I would rather prefer a smooth solution, without creating and loading a dump every single time. I just want to start a docker-compose file that mounts the data of the database and that's it: Very easy and nice solution.

Comment: I'm on the same boat with you. One of my workarounds is to copy the data during the docker image creation and/or use docker cp to copy everything from the container to my windows host.

Comment: Yeah, that also came in my mind. But I did a much a easier workaround for that: I use sqlcipher (encrypted sqlite3) as a filebased database. In that way I dont need to create a docker intance of a SQL based database. It's no a real solution, but in my case it helped me a lot. 

But there is still another way to do that: In your dockerfile, install git functionality. Create a script within this dockerfile, that allows you to checkout files from specific repositories. Now simply copy the files to your /var/lib/postgresql/data folder. 

Also make sure to switch to Linux containers!

Comment: I might miss your point but what if you run your container like: `docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d -v "D:\postgres:/postgresdata" -e PGDATA=/postgresdata postgres`. 

Your end result will be that your container is saving database info onto your Windows folder. I did not test anything with git, but I would assume that this should work.

Comment: In addtion to my previous comment: 

First you need to create a volume instead of hosted-volume: `docker volume create --name postgres-data -d local` and then use this volume in your docker run: `docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d -v postgres-data:/postgresdata -e PGDATA=/postgresdata postgres`